# Karate - get all specific field values from a response

Tags: karate

On karate 0.6.0, the following code returned an array with all the ids:

- def get = call read('wishlist-products-get.feature') id
- def wishlist = get.response.wishlist_products
- ids = wishlist[*].product_info.id

now on version 0.9.0 the same returns the following error:

wishlist[*].product_info.id, :1:9 Expected an operand but found *

Can someone tell me what change?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to catch up on a few rounds of release notes ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `get` keyword to save the results of a JsonPath expression [as described in the docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate#get).

```
* def ids = get wishlist[*].product_info.id
```

Comment: or use `* def ids = $wishlist[*].product_info.id`